# Laptop for programming/utility and getting into Linux

Tags: laptop, processor, linux, memory, displays

I've seen a lot of "Wich laptop should I buy?" questions but noone fits my needs.

I'm a web developer (situated in Italy) with actually no computer at home since mine power supply burned out (yeah it might sounds stupid but that's what it is) and I want to move into the laptops world.

This is what I'm looking for:

- I want to get into the world of linux distros and maybe install also windows (as I mainly work onto windows project), so i'm considering using a Dual Boot system.
- "*CPU > GPU*" As I will repair my old desktop pc with a new power supply, I will mainly play videogames into my old pc, so a super powerful Gpu isn't needed. Let's say that "*the heaviest game*" that I would play wuold be *League of legends* or something like that. Mainly I will program with this pc so a nice Cpu is the way I will go go.
- 16 gb of ram, so I can run as many tasks as I needs, but i think I can get away with 8 gb of ram.
- A nice keyboard is mandatory as I will be writing stuff all the times.
- The chances of me watching any movies on this pc are very high, so a decent display would be greatly appreciated.
- No particular requests regarding *the storage space* and *the noise of the fans*
- The thinner the better. But I could also consider *"thick" computers*
- Last but not least, the price. I wuold stay in the  500 euros range. The lower it is the better.

I've seen that many of you guys are recommending the *thinkpad*, but i don't know which model will fits my needs best as I'm not involved into hardware as I was before.

Comment: "`so i'm considering using a Dual Boot system`" - I would recommend against this. Yes, the o/s will run quicker natively, but rebooting is a pain. I recommend a Virtual Machine (specifically Virtual Box). That might need more RAM, though, to run both at once (although Linux needs far less RAM than Windows).

Comment: yeah it was my alternative... and I think i will go for it

Comment: I mean i still don't know wich laptop should I buy (and so install a virtual machine on it) xD

Comment: IC IC. I was once in a similar position, but base din Europe (you might want to post your location?), so bought a laptop from Amazon Germany which only had FreeDOS installed and thus avoided the "microsoft tax" which was over $100 at that time. You might want to consider not so much which to buy but where to buy it from. Btw, black friday sales might also make "when" a dimension in your choice.

Comment: I've edited my question with my location. Regarding the stores where should I buy the laptop.... actually the one with the best price

Comment: Upvote for the edit. But, when I said "where", I was not talking of stores, so much as countries. E.g. would you trust a laptop from AliExpress in China? It is likely to much cheaper than a similar laptop bought in Italy, even including postage, and about 50% of everything is now made in China (probably a higher figure for tech goods). Would you consider second hand, or refurbished? These will be cheaper and refurbished will have been checked thoroughly. Just a few more things to thing about

Comment: oh, sorry for the misunderstanding. I mean, I can of course consider a second hand laptop, but I prefer going for a brand new, as I will be holding this computer for a while .

Comment: For 30+ years, I have had nothing but laptops (the first being an Intel 8286).  A few times per year, I take it somewhere else, but these are so rare that every time I buy a new one, I ask myself why I don't buy a desktop, which will be cheaper, more powerful, accept larger hard-drives, more RAM ... just sayin'

Comment: I know that feeling... I'm actually looking for a new power supply into those black friday deals, so my desktop pc will be fixed as soon as possible. This is why i was looking for a brand new laptop, as at home I can use my desktop, now i want to take something that i can actually use also outside my home

Comment: I've been using Linux in my Laptop exclusively since 4 years ago and honestly, the most important thing is not the laptop but the Linux distribution you are about to use. Most distributions are made for desktops, so things like processor speed, overheating or battery life are not taken into account, also drivers for graphic cards are an issue too. You won't have issues with Intel cards, but you can have with others. After testing different distros, I've been using Linux Mint for a couple of years and it is the best I've tested so far; it has also improved a lot, so I'm quite happy with it.

Comment: Regarding the hardware, I use an old laptop (>5 years) with 8Gb RAM plus SSD drive and it works like a charm (boot time of around 8 to 10 seconds).

Comment: thanks for the advices @Carles, I've heard about mint and actually used a little bit a year ago ;D

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica, rebooting is relatively painless if you don't got enough ram.

Answer (score 2):

Not recommending a specific laptop (at least not at this stage anyway) but a couple of points, nevertheless:

1. Do not get one with a Broadcom wireless chipset - you won't be getting it to work with Linux without a lot of difficulty (involving NDIS wrappers, if even then). Avoid them like the plague and make sure you get one with an Intel wifi chipset.
2. I used to be the multiboot king back in the day but, these days, I wouldn't recommend it at all: whichever OS you're running, but most especially if it's Windows, if you get an infection, there's a good chance it'll worm its way in below your OS as a rootkit and subvert every other OS on on your system - and then there's *no* amount of 'more secure than Windows' goodness that you'll derive from Linux. Get a laptop with eSATA or a couple of external (SSD) drives that will boot from a USB port (I've even run a complete Arch setup from a simple USB key as my daily use box) and just plug in whichever one you need/want. (Or you could use the Linux Subsystem in Win10, with the caveat that it's prone to the same risk as a multiboot machine).

Comment: Thank you man, i will take in mind to not buy a computer wit a Broadcom wireless chipset

Comment: You're welcome - it's a nightmare trying to sort it out and I just gave up bothering a long time ago: if there *is* a way to persuade a Broadcom to work with an NDIS Wrapper I haven't found it yet (and, so far, it's the only option there ever even *has* been).